# Narrator issues with Popup in UWP XAML (Win 10) based Application

Tags: xaml, uwp, narrator

issue 1: We have designed popup in our application using Canvas (using grids) and when needed turning on the Z-Index and Visibility of the control.

Narrator also reads the data outside the popup (i.e. Background page) (caps + arrows). this is our issue.
We want to restrict that. Is there any way that this can be done.

Note: The popups we have designed using canvas, so that it can be placed anywhere

issue 2:  There are some pages which are flyout, on which there is a textblock. The problem for the current implementation is Narrator just read Popup Windows open when opening a flyout. I hope to reader a customized title for the popup window that can identify which window opened. I tried automationproperties.name for flyout, it does not helpful. I also tried to make the reader to use the textblock in the popup windows, via set the accessibility.view to "Control", it does not work either.

Could someone hit the same issue, any idea on how to make it work?

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: Please post the code that is failing. a minimal example is best.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of using the system narrator to read out the application's texts, use some logic in your application to read out selected text ?

Following code reads out text :

```
private async void SpeakOut(string speakOut)
    {
        MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
        var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
        Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(speakOut);
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();

    }
```

Comment: We are implement accessibility for our application. Hence forth, it should be compatible with narrator